# fail to install "go-plus" package in Atom under OSX 10.11.1

Tags: macos, go, atom-editor

I am a freshman on programming. I want to start with Golang. When I was installing  the "go-plus"package in Atom. I met with such a problem.

[image: problem screenshot]

Comment: http://elfxp.com/mac-xcrun-error/

Comment: try this command `sudo xcode-select -switch`